# Unexpected Signalr connection abort in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, firefox, signalr

I am using SignalR (with cross-domain request), version 2.3.0 for webchat integrated to ASP.NET site. Everything is working fine. But I found strange behaviour of SignalR connection. When I clicked to the reference from tab of the chat for file downloading SignalR connection was aborted and onDisconnected method was triggered in my Hub class. FireBug show me next POST-request:

http://*:81/signalr/abort?transport=longPolling&clientProtocol=1.4&token=eUpLNitKcmR1d2JhTTRvcHNVZmEwcG1EKzYvMElZbmg4aE5yam9xM3k0dz0_IjAsNGJmOWNhODUtNDU2NS00NWExLWFjMTgtNzgyN2FhZDA2Njg1LGxvY2FsaG9zdCI1&State=1&connectionToken=hDXe9xIZtmrapjl1LRwtK9B%2BfYMoeuHka8ctBLaPa0YnjiN9iiFa%2BvFMBHIGpGH0h8qPEDgGZSRGwjMw3Wm1DJi6cUPtZjLca6%2FR2576SGksLAj3lnPN1JWIlxMsn8%2Bf&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22c%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22voip%22%7D%5D, where * is my domain.

It is reproduced in Mozilla Firefox (version 30.0) for LongPolling or Websocket transports. How I can fix this problem? Or is it bug of SignalR or Firefox?

Comment: [This bug](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3109) has been recently filed against SignalR on GitHub. I'm not sure if you and bwalendz on GitHub are one in the same. If so, thanks for filing the issue! If not, following the link should provide more insight into the bug. For now, the workaround is to attach a handler to the client's `disconnected` event that will call `$.connection.start` again after a short `window.setTimeout`.

Comment: @halter73, yes. This is the same problem. Thanks for you help. Could you post your comment as answer please?

Comment: A short timeout followed by $.connection.start will not start the connection again using FireFox 51.0.1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This bug](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3109) has been recently filed against SignalR on GitHub. The basic idea is that downloading a file causes Firefox to trigger the `window.onbeforeunload` event which in turn causes SignalR to close any ongoing connections.

For now, the workaround is to attach a handler to the client's disconnected event that will call `$.connection.start` again after a short `window.setTimeout`.

You could also unbind SignalR's onbeforeunload handler: `$(window).unbind("beforeunload")`. The downside of doing this is that Firefox might not gracefully disconnect when the user leaves the page running SignalR. Without a graceful disconnect, SignalR will wait over 30 seconds before it times out the client and calls the `OnDisconnected`  handler on the `Hub` or `PersistentConnection`.

Comment: Neither of these methods worked for me; unbinding the beforeunload event has no effect and restarting a new connection doesn't help because the server is going to call back to a previous connection by id (that the client is no longer listening to).

Comment: Restarting the connection should work if you address clients by their user or group names instead of their connection ids. The following guide explains how to do this: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections

Answer (score 8):

I have managed to use the workaraound explained by [halter73](https://stackoverflow.com/users/719967/halter73) and I have solved the issue described by [dudeNumber4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74000/dudenumber4) resetting the connectionid inside the disconnect event so that the server kept calling back the right users based on their connectionid without the need to address them by their user or group names.

```
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $("#mySignalRConnectionIdHidden").val($.connection.hub.id);
        });
    }, 3000);  
});
```

Comment: this fix is working for me but could you please let me know what is the purpose of setTimeOut function here and what should be the value of the time i.e. 3000 ?

Comment: setTimeOut is just a way of delaying for a while the call to connection.hub.start after a disconnection happens. 3000 means 3 seconds, but again, that's just an example, you can set the value to whatever your need is :)

Comment: worked for me! actually you can set the timeout to zero, the call stack will be emptied and then the `start` function will be executed;

Comment: For ASP.NET Core 3+ users coming here, you can use `.withAutomaticReconnect()` when building the connection: `const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").withAutomaticReconnect().build();`