# Firefox SignalR connection dies

Tags: asp.net, firefox, signalr, signalr.client

Using Visual Studio 2015, ASP.NET MVC web application, SignalR 2 with jquery signalR 2.1.2.  One simple hub, nothing fancy in my configuration:

```
public partial class Startup  
    {  
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)  
        {  
            app.MapSignalR();  
        }  
    }
```

Here is the (working on 2/3 browsers) client code:

```
$.connection.hub.logging = true;  
$.connection.hub.start().done( function () {  
    connectionId = $.connection.hub.id; // posted up
} );  
uploadHub = $.connection.uploadHub;  

$.extend( uploadHub.client, {  
    exportFilePrepared: function (){  
        $( '#exportWait' ).modal( "hide" );  
    }
});
```

I have a page where downloadable files are requested.  When the post is made I'm showing a spinner overlay.  After the file has been built on the server, I'm calling a client function via SignalR to hide the overlay.

Browser results with logging on the client turned on:
**IE**:  Works.  Messages from SignalR:

- Keep alive has been missed, connection may be dead/slow.
- Keep alive has timed out.  Notifying transport that connection has been lost.
- Updating iframe src to 'host/signalr/recconnect?transport=foreverFrame...
- Triggering client hub event 'exportFilePrepared' on hub 'UploadHub'

**Chrome**:  Works.  Only message from SignalR:

- Triggering client hub event 'exportFilePrepared' on hub 'UploadHub'

**Firefox**:  Doesn't work.  Messages from SignalR:

- Stopping connection.
- EventSource calling close().
- Fired ajax abort async = false.
- Stopping the monitoring of the keep alive.

If I put a breakpoint on the log message "Stopping connection" above in firefox, it never hits.  Any clues how to further debug this?

Comment: You could also share the client code.

Comment: I've never had a problem like this. Try starting a fresh web app that does nothing but the above and work your way up from there...

Comment: OK, just finished with simplest example of what I described above.  Exact same results (Chrome fine, same messages from Firefox).  I do see a warning in the console, "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience."  It's logging that when I'm posting a form...

Comment: Turns out to be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24533223/unexpected-signalr-connection-abort-in-firefox